# Create a Twig Extension for loading images in a directory

Tags: php, twig

I am using Twig without Symfony for a projet.

I need in my template to load the contents of a directory to show it via HTML.

For this I need to create a Twig Extension, in PHP, which loads the contents name of the pictures I have in my directory, so that I can loop their names and get them in my template.

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out the Twig documentation on creating extensions? Also, you could simply be passing the data to the template, you don't have to extend the template engine for this.

Comment: Yep, that is what I did, thanks to Neil Masters for the solution below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not create an extension for this. Below is an example of how to implement it.

Add to your controller

```
$contents = glob("/foo/bar/path", "*");
```

Add to your twig

```
{% for content in contents %}
    // Display the images in an img tag?
    // List out the contents?
    // Whatever
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This solution is much simpler and works like a charm. I am new to twig so thats why my question might have looked stupid. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

You can create twig extension and service class which will give You files with type that You will give as param

```
class FilesService
{
    private $directoryPath;

    public function __construct($directoryPath)
    {
         $this->directoryPath = $directoryPath;
    }

    public function getImages()
    {
        return array();
    }

    public function getPdfs()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

You can even define this class as service.